# For a musical script, how much stage direction in relation to dialogue should there be?

Tags: dialogue

I'm having trouble getting to the page number I want for a musical I'm writing and would appreciate some advice!

Comment: Hello Bob! This question should be more clear about what you are asking. You mention page number, but then tags are about dialogue. You are writing a musical, but you don't mention how this is relevant to your need. Finally, your ask for advice is generic. This question risks to be closed by the community, so I suggest you to edit it to better explain what your problem is! Don't hesitate to ask for help, and please check the [help] page :)

Answer (score 1):

The formatting for stage scripts isn't as strict as for screenplays, but let's assume for the moment that you're using [screenplay format](https://screenwriting.io/what-is-standard-screenplay-format/), which has the advantage that every page takes about one minute's worth of screen time, so your page total is roughly equivalent to your runtime.  Clearly, in that case, **adding super-elaborate stage directions might make it look longer, but it doesn't actually make for a longer film (or play).**  In general, script directions are usually minimal and functional to allow the director/producer to bring their own vision to the finished product.

The situation is quite different than in writing a novel or story, where the settings appear only in the reader's mind, and the descriptions often make up a major part of the writing.  Here, if you've put in all the dialogue and actions, plus functional descriptions of characters and settings, your play is complete. **Your script isn't the sets and costumes, it's the dialogue and plot.** Tweaking the stage directions is nothing but rearranging the furniture.  So if your script is shorter than you expected, either you've written a shorter play (maybe a one-act or a sketch) or you need to add substantive material (a subplot, or a secondary conflict, perhaps).  For what it's worth, writing a shorter play isn't necessarily bad.  Better one solid act of pure gold than three acts of tedious padding.

With all that said, this is a musical.  **Much of the runtime will be taken up by songs.**  Depending on how many songs there are, and what the ratio of spoken to sung dialogue is, it is quite possible that your full length script could look quite a bit shorter than you expect.  If you include the song lyrics in the script and format them so they generally match that same 1 minute per page guideline, it might help you get a better sense of where you really are.